# Reset a DAO datetime field to nothing with VB6

Tags: date, vb6, dao

In an old VB6 program, I have a data control associated with text controls on a form. Some of table fields are datetime fields in the JET database.

There is no default value for the datetime fields, so when first displayed on the form they show up as blank. When they are eventually set, the text string is validated as a date and the data control duly updates the record.

If the user desires to erase the date (e.g., correction of prior data entry) they simply blank the field. No error occurs on the save, but the affected datetime fields are not updated. When the record is viewed again, the last entered date is visible.

Upon examination of the DataChanged property of the text control, I can see that the date value has changed to blank (= cNullString).

Therefore, I am assuming that the eventual save of the record ignores the cNullString because it considers it invalid for a datetime field.

When my user enters blank, how can I force the datetime field back to nothing so that the next time it is viewed it will be blank again?

Comment: Try entering 0. Dates are generally stored in units since a date. In Windows whole numbers are number of days and fractions are the time of the day since (1/1/1601??).

Comment: If I do that, I'll actually be entering a date and when the user views the record again they'll see that day 0 date. I want them to see blank. I'm also trying to avoid transformations, such as detecting day 0 and making the field blank, then restoring 0 before saving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If writing DAO code to clear a Date field, I found that I had to use "Empty". Null and "" won't work. So for field dtmDelivery (type Date), I had to use the following. strDelivery is just a string with the date in it.

```
        Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("tblSomething", dbOpenDynaset)
        If (strDelivery = "") Then                      
            rst!dtmDelivery = Empty    
        Else 
            rst!dtmDelivery = strDelivery
        End If
        rst.Update
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to set the TextBox.DataFormat to "Date" or a specific date format via the IDE.  Then the underlying StdDataFormat object should have its NullValue property = "" and it becomes effective.

As the docs say:

> Ignored when the **Type** property is set to fmtGeneral. The **NullValue** property is read each time a null field is fetched.

I'm not sure this can be set completely in code.  When set in the IDE at design-time you get the property set up as (US English locale here):

```
  BeginProperty DataFormat 
     Type            =   1
     Format          =   "M/d/yyyy"
     HaveTrueFalseNull=   0
     FirstDayOfWeek  =   0
     FirstWeekOfYear =   0
     LCID            =   1033
     SubFormatType   =   3
  EndProperty
```

However the `SubFormatType` seems to be the key and this property does not seem to be exposed for alteration at runtime.

**Note**

Tested against the ADO Data Control and not the aged DAO version.  However these binding properties transcend the ADO-DAO divide so this should be applicable.

Comment: I have never used DataFormat but experimented with it while I was researching this issue. When I try to set it, VB says "The DataFormat property is not supported for this DataSource. The data source in question is a standard VB data control. I assumed I was one version back (Access 97 instead of Access 2000). Nonetheless, your tip is very good information. Thanks.

Comment: Well it could be a DAO issue after all, or a Jet 3.x issue I suppose.  Sorry you can't use this, it did exactly what you asked for when I tried it with the ADO Data Control and a Jet 4.0 database.